# Help refactor a small piece of Javascript code which identifies user's referrer source

Tags: javascript, client-side, referrer

I've written the following small piece of javascript (Based on the excellent [parseURI](http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/) function) to identify where the user originated from. I am new to Javascript, and although the code below works, was wondering if there is a more efficient method of achieving this same result?

```
try {
        var path = parseUri(window.location).path;

        var host = parseUri(document.referrer).host;
        if (host == '') {
                alert('no referrer');
                }

        else if (host.search(/google/) != -1 || host.search(/bing/) != -1 || host.search(/yahoo/) != -1) {
                alert('Search Engine');
                }
        else {
                alert('other');
                }
        } 

catch(err) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the host check using alternative searches:

```
else if (host.search(/google|bing|yahoo/) != -1 {
```

I'd also be tempted to test document referrer before extracting the host for your "no referrer" error.

(I've not tested this).

Comment: Thanks! I just tested your suggestion to test the document referrer before extracting the host and it seems to work! Here's the updated code:   if (document.referrer) {
                var host = parseUri(document.referrer).host;

                if (host.search(/google|bing|yahoo/) != -1) {
                        alert('Search Engine');
                }
                else {
                        alert('other');
                }
        }
        else {
                alert ('direct');
        }

Comment: Be careful. This will also match `mygoogleclone.myevilsite.com`

Comment: Very good point. You could amend the regex for google (and the other sites) to something like "^www\.google\.(com|co\...)$". Although this would need careful testing (again, I've not tested this) to make sure it didn't result in any false negatives. Guess it depends how robust a check you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I end up defining a function called `set` in a lot of my projects. It looks like this:

```
function set() {
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        result[arguments[i]] = true;
    return result;
}
```

Once you've got the portion of the hostname that you're looking for...

```
// low-fi way to grab the domain name without a regex; this assumes that the
// value before the final "." is the name that you want, so this doesn't work
// with .co.uk domains, for example
var domain = parseUri(document.referrer).host.split(".").slice(-2, 1)[0];
```

...you can elegantly test your result against a list using JavaScript's `in` operator and the `set` function we defined above:

```
if (domain in set("google", "bing", "yahoo"))
    // do stuff
```

More info:

- http://laurens.vd.oever.nl/weblog/items2005/setsinjavascript/