# Basic Javascript RegExp to detect visitors coming from google

Tags: javascript, regex

I've to discover were the user come from and if he comes from google (search) I have to show a greeting box (in my blog).

I've a script really well done, but I don't know how to modify it to refer to all the visitors coming from google.

```
if(referrer == "http://www.smashingmagazine.com/"){
```

This is the part of the script to modify.

How can this match all the visitors coming from *google* (all the different possible urls).

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247207/help-refactor-a-small-piece-of-javascript-code-which-identifies-users-referrer-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
if (referrer.match(/google\.com/)) {}
```

?

Comment: pretty obvious solution, my fault. Thank you